# Need little help with jQuery & selectors (simple text without tags)

Tags: jquery

I have HTML:

```
<font color=darkgreen>18.96<br><b>18.95</b><br>18.94<br>18.92<br>18.88<br>18.86<br>18.53<br>18.51<br></font>
```

and i need to select 18.96. I tried with .children(0), but this return me 18.95.

Comment: What's your selector?  What are you trying to accomplish here?
sidenote...
Wow, font tags and jQuery.  That's kinda wrong :)

Comment: To Surreal's point, if you have any control over the code you should style w/ CSS and not the font tag.  The `<font>` tag has been deprecated since HTML4 spec in 1998.

Comment: i'm getting HTML from remote page and need to parse it.

Answer (score 7):

You need to access the *text* nodes: `children` find the child *elements*.  You can do this with the [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) function, which gets all the nodes contained by the element.

The first node is a text node `18.96`; the next is the `br` element, the third the `b` element, the fourth the `br`, etc.

```
var first = $('<font color=darkgreen>18.96<br><b>18.95</b><br>18.94<br>18.92<br>18.88<br>18.86<br>18.53<br>18.51<br></font>').contents()[0].nodeValue;
```

Note that this would be much more stable if you were able to wrap the values in tags, e.g. `span`.

Comment: +1 Too quick for me. :o) Though I assumed that it was an element in the DOM. Maybe not.

Comment: I'd just add that you need the `data` or `nodeValue` property to get the content of the text node.

Answer (score 1):

```
var aRes = $('font').html().split('<br>');
```

Your value is `aRes[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the text into `<span>` tags

Answer (score 0):

```
$("font").contents().eq(0).text()
```